# Categorical PCA: Merge categories based on Transformation Plots?

Tags: pca, data-transformation, ordinal-data

A tutorial on categorical pca (CATPCA) (Linting et al. 2012) explains that a decision to merge categories of an ordinal variable can be made based on the category quantification ("none of the transformation plots show extreme category quantifications, merging categories is not necessary." P.22).

The process of determination is not very clear or intuitive to me. How do you determine whether merging categories is warranted based on transformation plots? SPSS CATPCA produces a separate category quantification output but it is unclear how one gleans this info based on the transformation plots specifically.

REFERENCE

Linting, Mariëlle, and Anita van der Kooij. "Nonlinear principal components analysis with CATPCA: a tutorial." Journal of personality assessment 94.1 (2012): 12-25.

Comment: Do you have a link to download the article or can share it personally?

Comment: @ttnphns: It's available in [LibGen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_Genesis).

Comment: `How do you determine whether merging categories is warranted based on transformation plots?` On a monotonic (ordinal) transformation plot, if two or more adjacent levels (categories) are at the same vertical level, i.e. they are connected almost horizontally, they can be seen as "mergeable" because they almost don't differ when the variable is seen as interval, "optimally" scaled.